# Why do my egg shells have discoloration?

Tags: eggs

Why do my eggs have discolored spots on them? In the white eggs they look gray and in the brown eggs they look darker. I know brown eggs have speckles etc but these spots are not speckles.
Thanks

Comment: Pictures, please? Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Answer (score 4):

You didn't post pictures, so I'm going out on a limb here:

Looking at some eggs out of my fridge, I see grayish spots on some white eggs. They are hard to photograph, but I tried. Look especially at the blunt end:

[image]

If you hold the egg in front of a light source, the mystery is revealed - **thin shell areas** light up:

[image]

Your eggs simply have a thin shell. This may be caused by various reasons (older hens and lack of minerals amongst them), but is completely harmless as far as food safety and use in the kitchen is concerned.